# Old vs older usage

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-usage

How would you say if you see a celebrity on TV and she has wrinkles and grey hair now.

Would you say she looks old or she looks older?

Comment: What's the context? *Older* only works when used as a comparative. Older than the last time you saw her? Older than somebody else? In the right context it could be both: *Not only does she look **older** [than last time], but now she's also looking **old**.*

Comment: @JasonBassford where have you been in recent years? Logically you are, of course, correct, but the issue here is not logic but a particular view of politeness. In common parlance, at least in the UK, I am "an older person". If someone called me "an old person" that would carry a suggestion of physical and mental infirmity that is not implied by the word "older". It is illogical and absurd, but it does at least protect me from being called "old".

Comment: @JeremyC At a certain point, it's not meaningful to hold language hostage to political correctness. By your reasoning, **old** should be removed from the dictionary entirely just because it's not polite. That's not what this question is asking about. Regardless of where you draw the line, at some point the word **old** has a meaningful purpose to somebody. At what age, or in what situation, it's to be applied is something else entirely. This question is asking about the words themselves and what they mean in English. (The same could be said of **young** and **younger**, incidentally.)

Comment: @JeremyC - *Older* is fine in the polite "I'm an older person" sense that you described, but that usage doesn't fit with the OP's case of "she *looks* older". Also if the issue here is politeness then one wouldn't comment on somebody's wrinkles and grey hair at all, there's not really a polite way to say that somebody *looks* old.

Answer (score 0):

One useful rule here, drawn from a code of manners in the American South, is that we do not comment on the appearance of others-- not their weight, their complexion, their attire, or their state of wrinkledyness. Saying that someone "looks old" is insulting language, just as if, to a child, I were to say "you're just a baby" or "you're too young to understand". This is a case where the niceties of grammarians must yield to the niceties of social interaction. Here's a lesson:  Student comments on a former teacher who didn't like hiphop music because "she was old". Asked "How old was she?", student (first year, about 18 yo) replied, "At least 30."